# How do i implement the recurring payments on my website using paypal Buy Now Button ? i don't want to use subscription button..?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I want to implement to monthly recurring payments on my website but i don't want to use paypal 's subscription button but i will use Buy Now button instead. So what are the pros and cons of my approach and how do i implement it?

Comment: You can't. A 'Buy now' button constitutes a one-off purchase. A 'Subscription' button is a recurring payment, which, as the name suggests, recurs. If you want you can use a Subscription button and give it an *image* of a Buy Now button, though.

Comment: suppose i use monthly subscription thing on my website.so does the subscriber is automatically billed monthly or they are notified and given an option whether to continue subscription or not for this month.

Comment: And does the subscriber have to enter credit card no. and other details every month or only once during first time ?

Comment: Not sure how this is a programming question, but yes, they would be billed automatically every month without notification, and no, they wouldn't need to re-enter their credit card details every month.

Comment: Ok is there anyway by which user can renew thier plan manually every month.Becoz i don't want the automated billing.

Comment: Then it's not a recurring payment. That's a one-off payment that they buy every month, if they feel like it the next month.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last answer, I would suggest looking into using PayPal IPN in combination with a single 'Buy now' button.
By using IPN you can record and track each "subscription" in your database, and send all "subscribers" a notification email prior to the expiration of their "profile".

PayPal IPN allows you to (asynchronously) process order information while not having to depend on the buyer to return to your website to complete the order.

You can use IPN by setting up a script which receives this (POST) data from PayPal. In addition, you must include the following code in your button and/or API call(s):

For Website Payments Standard (where "xxxxxxxx" is the full URL to your IPN script):

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="xxxxxxxx">
```

You can find sample code, documentation and further information on PayPal IPN [here](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)